# Does purchasing in-game DLC qualify for missions for earning Gold Points?

Tags: my-nintendo

The smallest amount I would need to buy to earn Gold coins is $5 (in my territory).  I've been purchasing items individually in some games but they're always less than $5 each. Anything I would have bought that is $5 or more that I'm willing to pay for I've already purchased before My Nintendo went live.

**If I managed to come across a game that had DLC that was at least $5 and purchased it, would that purchase be eligible to earn Gold Coins?  Or is it limited to purchases made in the eShop?**

Comment: Aren't you redirect to the eShop anyway while buying a DLC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in-game DLC does not count towards your gold coins, even if it was more then $5. According to the mission description of all the eShop Gold Points missions:

> The mission applies to full software titles only. Any purchase of
>   add-on content or passes does not qualify as completing the mission.